# Can I remove a 32" portion of a supporting wall?

Tags: walls

[image]Update: Hopefully for better understanding, The wall showing the electric wall switch plate ( will note this wall as 'A'), I want to eliminate 32" from its end holding the 'Half wall' (will be wall 'B').

I would add two 2x10 the length of Wall (A) and tie it into to support Wall (B) but again 32" would be non supportive. So the electric plate would be removed etc.

Hopefully this makes it more clear.

I want to remove 32" of a supporting wall which connects to a supporting wall with two 2x10s which will hang 32" with no end support at the end but connect into the other supporting wall. The issue is the other supporting wall currently is a half wall that marries into the wall I want to remove the 32" from.

Simply, there will be an L shape with no under beam support for 32 inches, on one wall and the other wall which is a half wall now, will have 6 foot of un-support although the two 2x10s together which will further be 10 foot long married into the first supporting wall should support it.

This is a ranch-style home with no upstairs, just a low attic but ceiling rafter do connect on to that half wall.

Any help suggestions I would appreciate.

[image]

Comment: Diagram and/or pictures would help. Each worth 1,000 words at the current exchange rate.

Comment: Also be sure that the "rafters" you say connect to the half wall aren't just ceiling joists that don't actually carry roof loads. And, in carpentry, "half wall" usually refers to a half-_height_ wall. I suspect that we're talking about something else here.

Comment: I must say that with the apparent lack of understanding, and vague wording, the best bet for the OP would be to get a professional to do an on site inspection. Maybe do the work himself, but at least have a pro do the plan so there's a minimum of damage to property or life.

Comment: The photo helps, but I'm still at a loss for what you want to do. Please fix your words to help me help you.

Comment: try labeling your walls with names, then reference them that way. As it is, when you say wall it is very unclear or hard to keep track of which wall being referenced

Comment: That's not a 32" _half wall_, that's a 32" _header_. It doesn't come up from the ground (wall), it hangs down from the ceiling (header), and it is likely load bearing, just like the one in the background. It's highly likely that the corner to the right of the light switches is a large post carrying the weight of the header (and the rafters above) down to the slab/foundation below. I would _strongly_ recommend you do _nothing_ until you have a structural engineer look at your house. The few hundred $ you spend on that could save the collapse of your house.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you want to change, remove or do anything to a load bearing wall it is best to call a structural engineer to make sure you do not do something that can't be fixed or creates a dangerous situation for the occupants for that structure.  1 cut too many can cause a disaster. my 2 cents